# Outlook AppointmentItem-- how do I add some data into the RTF mail body when "send" is clicked

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, rtf, appointment

I develop an outlook Add-in use the VSTO with C#.

Step 1: I create a ribbon for appointment explore,when the ribbon button is clicked,read a `.rtf` file and insert the `.rtf` file into the Appointment body.

```
 try
 {
 Outlook.Inspector insp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
 Outlook.AppointmentItem meetingItem = insp.CurrentItem() as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
  if(meetingItem == null){
      MessageBox.Show("the meeting is null,create a meeting Item");
      meetingItem = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)insp.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);                   
    }
   if(meetingItem != null) {
    meetingItem.MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting;
    object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    Word.Application wordAppl;
    Word.Document wordDoc;
    Word.Selection wordSel = null;
    wordDoc = (Word.Document)insp.WordEditor;
    wordAppl = wordDoc.Parent as Word.Application;
    wordDoc.Activate();
   String path = "D://WordSendTest//template//en_US.rtf";
     String fileName = path.ToString();
     wordSel = (Word.Selection)wordAppl.Selection;
     wordSel.Range.Delete(ref missing, ref missing);
    object falseRef = false;
    wordSel.Range.InsertFile(fileName, ref missing, ref falseRef, ref falseRef, ref falseRef);
    }
   }
    catch (Exception ex)
     {
       MessageBox.Show("Robbin click error!"+ ex.ToString());
     }
```

step 2: when user click the "send button",capture the ItemSend Event.

```
 private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);         
        }
```

Step 3:insert some "string text" into the end of the email body.

```
  void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Outlook.Inspector insp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
            Outlook.AppointmentItem meeting = insp.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
            Word.Document wordDoc = insp.WordEditor as Word.Document;
            Word.Application wordApp = wordDoc.Parent as Word.Application;
            Word.Selection wordSel =(Word.Selection) wordApp.Selection;
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            object units = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdStory;
            object findEnd = (object)"~-----~~-----~-----~-----~-----~-----~\r";
            object wholeWord = true;
            wordSel.HomeKey(ref units, ref missing);
            if(wordSel.Find.Execute(ref findEnd,ref missing,ref wholeWord,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing))
            {
            wordSel.MoveUp(ref missing,ref missing,ref missing);
            wordSel.TypeText("--=Head for Insert info =--\n");
            wordSel.TypeText("when user click the <send button>,the Tex info will be insert and show here \n");
            wordSel.TypeText("--=End for Insert info=--\n");
            }
            else {
               MessageBox.Show("not fonud the END tag");
            }
        }
```

Problem:
in debug model,add Text is insert into the body successfully when the send button is clicked.
but, the mail which is actually sent out is not changed,only same before the "send button" is clicked.
when I open the appointment in calendar, the body is OK,text is insert into the end of the mail body successfully.

so ,who know why?why the mail is not sent out with the update body ,but the update mail body is saved in the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

What is your code that modifies the text? When is it executed?
Keep in mind that appointments are never sent. When you click Send, Outlook creates a MeetingRequest obejct and sends it instead. The only time you can modify that object is when you process the Application.ItemSend event.

Comment: Dear, I add my code in the question,looking forward your reply.thanks.

Comment: As I mentioned before, you need to work with the item (MeetingItem) passed to your ItemSend event handler. Your code works with Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem (AppointmentItem). It is too late to modify AppointmentItem, the new MeetingItem object had already been created. You need to work with that object and set the MeetingItem.RtfBody property appropriately.

Comment: Hi,I try again,but also not work.. today I find an article on Miscrosoft website called [Cannot change body of meeting request in Send and ItemSend events](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2605734/en-us?sd=rss&spid=14864),they say "The WordEditor property is available in Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010 and returns a Microsoft Word Document object. Changes made using this property in the Send or ItemSend event are not saved." maybe the Microsoft do not support my this request?

Comment: As I have previously mentioned, you need to use the Meetingtem.RtfBody property. Forget about the Inspector object.